Problema con visualización de PDF en modal
tengo un programa donde se visualiza PDF's, el tema es que lo hace en páginas distintas y yo quiero mostrarlo en la página principal por medio de un modal.
Tengo tres archivos dos php y un js, esto es lo que tengo:
busqueda.php
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="modalPDF">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe src='' id="pdf" width='1000px' height='700px'></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Solicitar préstamo.</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

es el modal donde se debe visualizar el pdf
js:
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: true,
    calendarWeeks : true,
    clearBtn: false,
    disableTouchKeyboard: true,
});

$("#boton").on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'filtros.php',
        data: $("#form1").serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(respuesta){
            $("#tabla").html(respuesta)
        }
    })
})

})
llamada por js a un php donde se visualiza una tabla con los datos y el vinculo del PDF.
filtro.php
if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
            $mostrar = "<script src='js/main.js'></script>
                        <table class='table-bordered m-4 text-center' style= 'font-size: 13px;'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Ejercicio Físcal</td>
                                    <td>Ramo</td>
                                    <td>Institución</td>
                                    <td>Número de Documento Solicitante</td>
                                    <td>Número de Recepción</td>
                                    <td>Fecha de Recepción</td>
                                    <td>Folio SIAF</td>
                                    <td>Número de Documento Tramitante</td>
                                    <td>Concepto</td>
                                    <td>Importe</td>
                                    <td>Documento</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>";
            while($datos = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
                $mostrar .= "    <tr>
                                    <td>".$datos['ejercicio']."</td>
                                    <td>".$datos['ramo']."</td>
                                    <td>".$datos['no_institucion']."</td>
                                    <td>".$datos['num_documento']."</td>
                                    <td>".$datos['no_recepcion']."</td>
                                    <td>".$datos['fecha_recepcion']."</td>
                                    <td>".$datos['folio_siaf']."</td>
                                    <td>".$datos['ndoc_spf']."</td>
                                    <td>".$datos['concepto']."</td>
                                    <td>$".$datos['total']."</td>
                                    <td><a href='pdf.php?id=".$datos['id_documento']."'>".$datos['vinculo']."</td>
                                </tr>";
            }
            echo "    </tbody>
                        </table>";
        }else{
            $mostrar .= "No hay datos con esas características.";
        }
        echo $mostrar;

donde hacemos referencia para abrir el pdf es esta parte del parrafo
<td><a href='pdf.php?id=".$datos['id_documento']."'>".$datos['vinculo']."</td>

y lo manda a otro php, y se visualiza en otra  página, yo quiero que se visualice en el modal de la página principal.
Espero puedan ayudarme, con alguna sugerencia por favor y perdón si no me explique bien, es mi primera vez publicando aquí.
Por cierto, todos los datos son extraidos desde un consulta en mysql
